# Jhipster doesn't create domain classes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, jhipster

How're you doing?
I have a application that was generated with Jhipster 4.4.1. Now I want to upgrade to the last version of Jhipster. I started by running the `jhipster upgrade`, but since there was many errors, I decided to export the model to jdl using `jhipster export-jdl` command. But when trying to import the exported file, all the classes (dto, service, mapper, repository, resource) and front-end files are created for all the entities except the entities themselves. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: do not do upgrade directly, do eventually, use --target-version like 4.4.1 to 5 then 6 so on , yes its tedious but it will did the job,

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade? Cut off the links with JHipster in your project and update dependencies. Unless your project is trivial, it should have much custom code, so why worry about JHipster anymore?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou the project was generated with AngularJs as front-end framework. Now we want to migrate to AngularX. That's why we want to upgrade and let Jhipster generate a project with AngularX. Do you have a solution to upgrade from angularJs to angularX ?

Comment: The only solution is to rewrite your frontend, jhipster upgrade won't be of any help to you. One thing that could help you is to generate a new project with latest JHipster using your existing JDL and then adapt manually the generated code for your custom code.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thanks for your suggestion, I think I'll generate a new project with the latest version of Jhipster.